# Reactive Extensions: buffer until subscriber is idle

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a program where I'm receiving events and want to process them in batches, so that all items that come in while I'm processing the current batch will appear in the next batch.

The simple TimeSpan and count based Buffer methods in Rx will give me multiple batches of items instead of giving me one big batch of everything that has come in (in cases when the subscriber takes longer than the specified TimeSpan or more than N items come in and N is greater than count).

I looked at using the more complex Buffer overloads that take [Func<IObservable<TBufferClosing>>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229432%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or [IObservable<TBufferOpening> and Func<TBufferOpening, IObservable<TBufferClosing>>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229621%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), but I can't find examples of how to use these, much less figure out how to apply them to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: [This page](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/rx-part-9join-window-buffer-and-group.html) might help with the Buffer overloads. The whole series is very helpful

Comment: Have you tried `BufferBlock` in TPL Dataflow?

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
var xs = new Subject<int>();
var ys = new Subject<Unit>();

var zss =
    xs.Buffer(ys);

zss
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(zs =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("-", zs));
        ys.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    });

ys.OnNext(Unit.Default);
xs.OnNext(1);
Thread.Sleep(200);
xs.OnNext(2);
Thread.Sleep(600);
xs.OnNext(3);
Thread.Sleep(400);
xs.OnNext(4);
Thread.Sleep(300);
xs.OnNext(5);
Thread.Sleep(900);
xs.OnNext(6);
Thread.Sleep(100);
xs.OnNext(7);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

My Result:

```
1-2-3
4-5
6-7
```

Comment: Removing ObserveOn to make the program execute on one thread causes it to break.

Comment: @ChrisEldredge - Yes it does. You may have to allow multi-threading to get this to work.

Comment: It would also cause a busy wait when the queue is empty (pegs a CPU at 100%). If you remove the sleep when zs.Count == 0, you'll see the spike.

Comment: @ChrisEldredge - Maybe I should try something else. :-(

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something to buffer the values and then when the worker
is ready it asks for the current buffer and then resets it. This can
be done with a combination of RX and Task

```
class TicTac<Stuff> {

    private TaskCompletionSource<List<Stuff>> Items = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Stuff>>();

    List<Stuff> in = new List<Stuff>();

    public void push(Stuff stuff){
        lock(this){
            if(in == null){
                in = new List<Stuff>();
                Items.SetResult(in);
            }
            in.Add(stuff);
        }
    }

    private void reset(){
        lock(this){
            Items = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Stuff>>();
            in = null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Stuff>> Items(){
        List<Stuff> list = await Items.Task;
        reset();
        return list;
    }
}
```

then

```
var tictac = new TicTac<double>();

IObservable<double> source = ....

source.Subscribe(x=>tictac.Push(x));
```

Then in your worker

```
while(true){

    var items = await tictac.Items();

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    for each (item in items){
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: I suppose this works, but why use Reactive Extensions at all if I have to code directly with TPL/APM?

Comment: ReactiveExtensions is a framework. You can extend it as you wish. I often add my own operators for custom stuff

Comment: @ChrisEldredge To be fair, what you're asking isn't suited for the Rx framework; there's no way for the subscriber to signal to the observer that it is idle or not, you have to do that out-of-band.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this before is to pull up the ObserveOn method in DotPeek/Reflector and take that queuing concept that it has and adapt it to our requirements. For example, in UI applications with fast ticking data (like finance) the UI thread can get flooded with events and sometimes it cant update quick enough. In these cases we want to drop all events except the last one (for a particular instrument). In this case we changed the internal Queue of the ObserveOn to a single value of T (look for ObserveLatestOn(IScheduler)). In your case you want the Queue, however you want to push the whole queue not just the first value. This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an expansion of @Enigmativity's answer. I have used this to solve the problem:

```
public static IObservable<(Action ready, IReadOnlyList<T> values)> BufferUntilReady<T>(this IObservable<T> stream)
{
    var gate = new BehaviorSubject<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid());

    void Ready() => gate.OnNext(Guid.NewGuid());

    return stream.Publish(shared => shared
        .Buffer(gate.CombineLatest(shared, ValueTuple.Create)
            .DistinctUntilChanged(new AnyEqualityComparer<Guid, T>()))
        .Where(x => x.Any())
        .Select(x => ((Action) Ready, (IReadOnlyList<T>) x)));
}

public class AnyEqualityComparer<T1, T2> : IEqualityComparer<(T1 a, T2 b)>
{
    public bool Equals((T1 a, T2 b) x, (T1 a, T2 b) y) => Equals(x.a, y.a) || Equals(x.b, y.b);
    public int GetHashCode((T1 a, T2 b) obj) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

The subscriber receives a Ready() function to be called when ready to receive next buffer. I don't observe each buffer on the same thread to avoid cycles, but I guess you could break it some other place, if you need each buffer to be handled on the same thread.

Comment: This is a quite genius solution!